# usage of more common/more frequently/more often

Tags: adjectives, comparisons

Imagine this conversation between 2 persons :-
Person A to Person B: This event never takes place.
Person B to Person A: ***This event is more common*** (meaning takes place  at regular intervals) ***than you think***.

Person A to Person B: This event never takes place.
Person B to Person A: ***This event takes place more frequently*** (occurs more than once) ***than you think***.

Person A to Person B: This event never takes place.
Person B to Person A: ***This event takes place more often*** (event occurs more than once) ***than you think***.

Is the usage of *more common*/*more frequently*/*more often* correct in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think any of those replies would be made in answer to an assertion that something *never* happens. B would say something like "Yes, it does - more often than you might think."

The replies you suggest would be more appropriate if A had said "This event *hardly ever* happens."

Comment: In casual conversation, a simple reply of "It happens more often than you think," would be a very valid and natural response to counter Person A's claim; especially if actually talking when the speaker can use their tone of voice. In formal speech/writing it might be frowned upon though.