# Proper usage of 'more often' , 'more frequent'.?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

When we read an article on the internet saying that some Event X takes place more often than you think. What is in the mind of the author who writes this article? Does the usage of more often  implies that

1.)the author thinks that readers of his article already think that the event takes place at a lower frequency level

OR

2.)the author thinks that his audience might think that event never takes place ,

OR

3.) both scenarios 1and 2 are possible?

Also can anyone tell what exactly the usage of more common and more often implies in day to day English conversations??

Comment: I would consider 2) a special case of 1), when the frequency is zero. In either case the author is assuming her/his readers (and likely the general public) think the event occurs less frequently than it does.

Comment: @gorlux your comment deserves to be expanded to become an answer. Some readers without a physical science background may benefit from explanation of zero frequency.

Comment: Compare https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/540585/usage-of-more-common-more-frequently-more-often